# What 3D editor tool should I use with Panda3D

Tags: python, panda3d

I was trying to convert an `.obj` with a `.mtl` file to `.egg` file through `obj2egg`. After conversion, when I checked the `.egg` file with `pview`, it was in all white. I am using Microsoft 3D Builder since it is pre-installed on my PC. I would be glad to hear from you where I have made a mistake. I suppose it is for MS 3D Builder, what 3D editor tool would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Blender 3d have an extension to export .egg file. The file format it is used to by Panda 3d game engine.
Here is one link from Panda 3d Manual
http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Converting_from_Blender
You may find more answers and help after read the manual and asking the community.
 One more help offered in blender artists forum. 
https://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?11-Python-Support